# Sending HTML emails from sendmail module

Tags: commerce, emails, 7

I was using SMTP authentication and drupal mail module for sending HTML emails.

Suddenly emails are not going. Hence i disabled the SMTP module and directly send emails using drupal email but emails are not receiving in HTML format.

```
//Email hook function
```

`function caps_lead_mail($key,&$message,$params) {
switch ($key) {
  case 'send_link':
    $message['headers'] = array_merge(
      $message['headers'], array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed',`

```
    'bcc' => $params['bcc'],
  )
);
$message['subject']=t($params['subject']);
$message['body'][]=$params['body'];
```

`break;
}
}
//Sending html email
     $sender = "ce.com";
     $subject ="Weekly Report of new profiles and visit log";
     $message = '<h4>No new profiles and visit log </h4>';
     $message .= "Note: This is auto generated Email please do not reply to this Email.";
     $params = array(
     'body' => $message,
     'subject' => $subject,
     'headers'=>'simple',
     'bcc' => 'ce.com',
   );
      $to = "ce.com";
      drupal_mail('caps_lead', 'send_link', $to, language_default(), $params, $sender, TRUE);'`